# Why does std::basic_string have two separate template parameters _Elem (char type) and _Traits (char traits)?

Tags: c++, stdstring, char-traits

The problem is I don't understand why those should be separate. Why not use one class, like CharType, that would contain both the logic of char traits and char type.
I mean replace that:

```
template <class _Elem, class _Traits = char_traits<_Elem>, class _Alloc = allocator<_Elem>>
class basic_string { /*...*/ };
```

with that:

```
template <class ExtendedTraits, class _Alloc = allocator<_Elem>>
class basic_string { /*...*/ };
```

where ExtendedTraits is the presaid combination of _Elem and _Traits, that might look like that:

```
template<_CharType> //all the necessary template parameters
class extended_traits 
{
public:
    using value_type = _CharType;
private:
    _CharType _elem;
public:
//... all methods, that used to be in char_traits but now non-static and accepting one parameter

};
```

I tried to implement both approaches, both of them do work, but there may be some problems I still do not notice.

Comment: What do you prefer to see, `basic_string<char>` or `basic_string<extended_char_traits<char>>`?

Comment: If one were to trace the history and the lineage of `basic_string`, it's almost a certainty that we'll find that the char type came first, and the traits type was added as an additional, defaulted template parameter in order to preserve backwards compatibility with existing code.

Comment: The `char` traits *could* have been presumed & referred to, rather than have them be a parameter with a default value.  But then they couldn't be varied for (say) needed `char` that had different traits.  And likely the original `string` did just that (see Sam's comment).

Comment: actually there do have `Traits::char_type` that match `_Elem` (and the allocator's `value_type`)

Comment: I think it just make sense, I want a container of `char`, the trait and allocator is just additional to it.

Comment: But we never even happen to use basic_string<char>, we usually take advantage of merely std::string. It's quite transparent to an external user whether std::string is defined as basic_string<extended_ch_traits<char>,...> or basic_string<char, char_traits<char>,...>.

Comment: @CapyMaths btw, your replacement simply doesn't work, because of lack of `_Elem` definition.

Comment: How about extended_ch_traits<char>::value_type?

Comment: @CapyMaths `char_trait` doesn't have `value_type` either, nor is yours.

Comment: @CapyMaths anyway the point is you don't need to specify what default is good enough. why specify the whole trait while [the default one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) works?

Comment: @appleapple still can't grasp why we can't we achieve this using my "approach". We could create some base `class char_traits` with default definitions and then override all we need via inheritance just as stl developers do. Suppose `extended_traits` would also contain `value_type`. Now we can create our own string accustomed to my "concept of traits" :    `using string = my_string<extended_traits<char>,...>;` What's the problem here?

Comment: "But we never even happen to use" Until we see our first compiler error, or start using a debugger.

Comment: @CapyMaths  of course you can do it in many ways and it would compile, not saying it'd make sense (at least for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to separate the character type from the `Traits` object. `Traits` is an additional class for character comparisons and such, which is inherently different from the character type. Your method would work, but the equivalent would be like combining two completely different functions into the same function.

It's also more immediately obvious what character type the string is using. For example:

```
typedef string basic_string<char>;
```

is much more obvious than

```
typedef string basic_char<extended_traits<char>, ...>;
```

as there is an additional level of nesting and more characters and such.

At the end of the day, we don't care about what `Traits` is, we care about what character type the string is. `Traits` is for internal operations, and is meant to be abstracted away; as such, it's kept away from the character type, which is meant to be more obvious as it indicates what types of values the string can contain.

At least, that's my view on things.

Besides, it's not necessarily a bad thing to have more template arguments for `std::basic_string`, especially since there's only ever one template argument you really need to define a parameter for - the other template are given default types. It's not often that I would need to define my own `Traits` class. But if I wanted to define my own separate string class with a custom character or something like that, I would have to define a `Traits` class for it, even if I have written my assignment operator and comparison operators and everything else. That would be especially irritating.

Comment: actually `Trait::char_­type` must match  the container type.

Comment: Yes, the default type for ```Traits``` is ```std::char_traits<_Elem>```

Comment: ah, yes, then the "It's be annoying" doesn't make sense.